# how to include the image for plot linestyle legend in a text box

Tags: python, matplotlib, textbox, legend

When we call `legend`, the box has that little picture which shows the linestyle/marker style used my the plot together with the text. I want to get that image for plot (a small section of a a solid line and a dashed line) and include them in a text box.

The closest I have got is something like the following:

```
stable, = ax.plot(np.arange(10),np.arange(10),linestyle='solid', linewidth=5,color='k')
unstable, = ax.plot(np.arange(10),np.arange(10),linestyle='dashed', linewidth=3, color='k')
ghost, = ax.plot(0,0) # just to make some space in the legend box
ax.legend([ghost,stable,unstable],['Some text','some text', 'some text',loc='lower left')
```

However, for the texts I wanna include, I think it will be easier to use a separate `text` box and include that 'image' I see in the usual `legend` box as I need to refer to it multiple times. How to do this?

Comment: You can create a `DrawingArea` and place any artist in it. Apart, I'm not sure I understand the issue.

Comment: I'm now reading `DrawingArea` as you suggested. Basically I want to write the text "(solid line segment) stands for A. (dashed line segment) stands for B" in a text box placed inside my figure. I'm not sure how to get that (solid line segment) and refer to it.

Comment: That sounds a lot like what a legend is actually doing. So I would indeed use a legend for that. Else, you might use an `HPacker` with several offsetboxes in it.. but that's really utterly complictated.

Comment: I thought about using a legend but I will need to call that (line segment) multiple times, and it seems that I have a lot less flexibility to actually format all the stuff inside the legend box e.g. the (line segment) has to appear on the left on each separate line followed by the text (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Yes, or on the right side, but always the same side. It's just that matplotlib does not have a concept of floating objects, as one might know from word processors or HTML/CSS. So anything you build will quickly become pretty complicated.